# ggpattern missing pattern after na values

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using ggpattern, how can I not show a pattern for "NA" values but then have patterns continue after that point? When I run this code, there are no more patterns after an "NA" value even though there should be.

```
library(swimplot)
library(ggpattern)
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  study_id = c(3, 3, 3,3), primary_therapy = c("Si", "Si", "Si", "Si"),
  additional_therapy = c("NA", "S", "NA", "V+S"), end_yr = c(0.08, 0.39, 3.03, 3.4)
)

swimmer_plot(
  df = df, id = "study_id",
  end = "end_yr", name_fill = "primary_therapy",
  width = 0.85, color = NA) + 
  geom_col_pattern(aes(study_id, end_yr,
    pattern = additional_therapy), color=NA,
    fill = NA,
    show.legend=FALSE, width=0.85,
    pattern_spacing = 0.01, pattern_fill="black", pattern_color=NA,
    pattern_size = 0.5, pattern_density=0.1,
    pattern_linetype = 0.5, pattern_orientation="vertical") +
  scale_pattern_manual(name="Additional Therapy", values = c("S"="stripe","V"="circle","V+S"="crosshatch","NA"="none"))
```

Comment: Your `df` seems to be missing an extra value for `study_id` -- `study_id` only has 3 values while the rest of your variables have 4, so your code doesn't make a dataframe.

Comment: should be fixed sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Your question has two parts: 1) controlling the legend labels and 2) fixing the x-axis for `geom_col_pattern()`.

For your first question, you can remove `"NA"` from the legend by converting `additional_therapy` to a factor:

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(additional_therapy = factor(additional_therapy, 
                                     levels = c("S", "V", "V+S", "NA")))
```

Then, you can specify `breaks` to control which legend labels show up:

```
+ scale_pattern_manual(name="Additional Therapy", breaks = c("S", "V", "V+S"), values = c("S"="stripe", "V"="circle", "V+S"="crosshatch", "NA"="none"))
```

However, to the best of my knowledge, there is a problem with `ggpattern` when it comes to repeating patterns. I was able to recreate this issue using base `ggplot2` to confirm that it's not an issue with `swimplot`.

In the below code, you can see that `fill` acts appropriately, but `pattern` will never repeat twice, which causes the pattern from `"S"` to spill over into the second red bar, which shouldn't have any pattern because it's `"NA"`. I recommend [submitting an issue on Github](https://github.com/coolbutuseless/ggpattern/issues).

```
library(ggpattern)
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  study_id = c(3, 3, 3, 3), primary_therapy = c("Si", "Si", "Si", "Si"),
  additional_therapy = c("NA", "S", "NA", "V+S"), end_yr = c(0.08, 0.39, 3.03, 3.4)) 

df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = end_yr, y = study_id)) + 
  geom_col_pattern(aes(pattern = additional_therapy, 
                       fill = additional_therapy),
                   color = NA,
                   show.legend = TRUE,
                   position = "fill",
                   width = 3,
                   pattern_spacing = 0.01,
                   pattern_fill = "black",
                   pattern_color = NA,
                   pattern_size = 0.5,
                   pattern_density = 0.1,
                   pattern_linetype = 0.5,
                   pattern_orientation = "vertical") +
  scale_pattern_manual(
    name = "Additional Therapy",
    breaks = c("S", "V", "V+S"),
    values = c("S" = "stripe", "V" = "circle", "V+S" = "crosshatch", "NA" = "none"))
```

[image]