# ggpattern change stripe angle for one element

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I change the angle of the stripe pattern in only one element? For example, I want only the stripe pattern of "V" to be at -30 degrees.

Also, there seems to be an issue with my "NA" values / none pattern and no pattern appears after a NA value.

```
library(swimplot)
library(ggpattern)
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  study_id = c(3, 3, 3,3), primary_therapy = c("Si", "Si", "Si", "Si"),
  additional_therapy = c("NA", "S", "NA", "V+S"), end_yr = c(0.08, 0.39, 3.03, 3.4)
)

swimmer_plot(
  df = df, id = "study_id",
  end = "end_yr", name_fill = "primary_therapy",
  width = 0.85, color = NA) + 
  geom_col_pattern(aes(study_id, end_yr,
    pattern = additional_therapy), color=NA,
    fill = NA,
    show.legend=FALSE, width=0.85,
    pattern_spacing = 0.01, pattern_fill="black", pattern_color=NA,
    pattern_size = 0.5, pattern_density=0.1,
    pattern_linetype = 0.5, pattern_orientation="vertical") +
  scale_pattern_manual(name="Additional Therapy", values = c("S"="stripe","V"="stripe","V+S"="crosshatch","NA"="none"))
```

Answer (score 1):

For demonstration purposes, I changed your dataframe so you can see how the levels of `additional_therapy` get plotted, since your example dataframe didn't include any appearances of the level `"V"`.

To achieve your goal of changing the stripe element for one level of `additional_therapy`, you need to add the argument `pattern_angle` back into `geom_col_pattern` and then add an extra line for `scale_pattern_angle_manual()` to specify which levels' patterns get set at which angles.

```
library(swimplot)
library(ggpattern)
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  study_id = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3), 
  primary_therapy = c("Si", "Si", "Si", "Si", "Si"),
  additional_therapy = c("NA", "NA", "S", "V", "V+S"), 
  end_yr = c(0.08, 1.11, 2.11, 3.03, 3.4)
) 

# Convert additional_therapy to ordered factor (optional but highly recommended)
# This just determines the order that the items in the Additional Therapy legend appear in
df <- df %>% mutate(additional_therapy = factor(additional_therapy, levels = c("S", "V", "V+S", "NA")))

swimmer_plot(
  df = df, id = "study_id",
  end = "end_yr", name_fill = "primary_therapy",
  width = 0.85, color = NA) + 
  geom_col_pattern(aes(study_id, end_yr,
                       pattern = additional_therapy,
                       pattern_angle = additional_therapy
                       ), 
                   color=NA,
                   fill = NA,
                   show.legend=TRUE, # so you can see the legend 
                   width=0.85,
                   pattern_spacing = 0.01, 
                   pattern_fill="black", 
                   pattern_color=NA,
                   pattern_size = 0.5, 
                   pattern_density=0.1,
                   pattern_linetype = 0.5, 
                   pattern_orientation="vertical") +
  scale_pattern_manual(name="Additional Therapy", values = c("S"="stripe","V"="stripe","V+S"="crosshatch","NA"="none")) +
  scale_pattern_angle_manual(name="Additional Therapy", values = c(30, -30, 30, 30))
```

[image]

Unfortunately, to the best of my knowledge, there is a problem with `ggpattern` that is causing the issue with the x-axis. [I discussed it in another of your questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75269886/14992857). I confirmed that it wasn't an issue with `swimplot`.

Comment: This code is still incorrect. additional_therapy = c("NA", "NA", "S", "V", "V+S"), end_yr = c(0.08, 1.11, 2.11, 3.03, 3.4) but in the graph "V" does not end at 3.03 and the values of the axes is completely off .

Comment: You're right that the x-axis is still off. As far as I am aware, this is caused by an issue with `ggpattern`. I've updated my answer and provided a link to one of your other questions where I reproduced the issue.