# ggpattern and swimplot : issue with aligning patterns and repeating x-axis values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am having a hard time figuring out how to fix this graph. I thought it was a bug with ggpattern (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75252694/ggpattern-missing-pattern-after-na-values) and response to my bug report [here](https://github.com/coolbutuseless/ggpattern/issues/93)); however, others seem to think it is not a bug, but an issue with "overlapping columns". When there are no overlapping patterns/values (e.g., "NA, "S", "V+S") the x-axis and patterns align; but when some repeat as in the code above the problems occur. I do not know how to reconcile these packages together to create a graph with appropriate patterns and x-axis values which consistently seem to both be incorrect. Thanks!

```
library(swimplot)
library(ggpattern)
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  study_id = c(3, 3, 3, 3), primary_therapy = c("Si", "Si", "Si", "Si"),
  additional_therapy = c("NA", "S", "NA", "V+S"), end_yr = c(0.08, 0.39, 3.03, 3.4))


df <- df %>% mutate(additional_therapy = factor(additional_therapy, 
levels = c("S", "V", "V+S", "NA")))

    swimmer_plot(
      df = df, id = "study_id",
      end = "end_yr", name_fill = "primary_therapy",
      width = 0.85, color = NA) + 
      geom_col_pattern(aes(study_id, end_yr,
        pattern = additional_therapy), color=NA,
        fill = NA,
        show.legend=FALSE, width=0.85,
        pattern_spacing = 0.01, pattern_fill="black", pattern_color=NA) +
      scale_pattern_manual(name="Additional Therapy", values = c("S"="stripe","V"="circle","V+S"="crosshatch","NA"="none"), 
breaks=c("S","V","V+S"))
```